# Form validation of child component doesn't appears errors [Angular material]

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-material2

I have a form with single child component. But submitting the form I can't see any errors for the child component. Errors appear just for input embedded directly in form

Here is example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvcwnh , click on submit button then you'll show one error on the first input

[ Angular, Angular material]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a very complicated form and multiple child components. The best solution I came up with, was to validate all of the form fields immediately after clicking the submit button with this function

```
validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup | FormArray): boolean {
  const keysArray = formGroup instanceof FormGroup ? Object.values(formGroup.controls) : formGroup.controls;
  keysArray.forEach(control => {
    if (control instanceof FormControl) {
      control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: false });
      control.updateValueAndValidity();
    } else if (control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray) {
      this.validateAllFormFields(control);
    }
  });
  return formGroup.invalid;
}

send() {
  const formIsValid = this.validateAllFormFields(this.testForm);
}
```

This is the fixed version of your code (I just added the above code to `app.component.ts`)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbzubh

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by couple of ways:
One of the way i can think is When you are trying to submit the form, you are can check the status of the child component. You can do so by adding some input property to your child component and assigning the validation function tot the same in the child component. At present, even if your child component's state is invalid, there is no validation invoked.